# How can I access to outlook folders which have MS Exchange Account

Tags: outlook, exchange-server-2010

I have written the following code to access outlook folders.

```cs
MSOutlook.Application app = new MSOutlook.Application();
MSOutlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
try
{
    foreach (MSOutlook.Folder folder in ns.Folders)
    {
        ...
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

but this code throw exception at `ns.Folders` and this exception means

> The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA).

However, I can get folders using the same code in the environment which has no exchange account.

How can I get the folders in the environment which has MS Exchange account?

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

        Outlook._NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.MAPIFolder taskFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder folder in ns.Folders)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Folder ----"+folder.Name.ToString());
            }
```

This works for me fine..